# Polling server from background android

Tags: android, web-services, service, polling

In android application i am polling server from service(foregrounded) at every X minutes(this is necessary). I am getting proper response every time when application running in foreground but, when app is running in background, after some successful responses i am getting "connection refused" error every time.

I don't understand why it is not working in background.

```
WifiService(  972): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@9a93161}
V/LocationPolicy(  972): onProcessStateChanged
D/LBSSystemMonitorService(  972): handleMessage what - 3
D/Wiper_jni(  972): Send Network Location.
V/NotificationService(  972): enqueueNotificationInternal: pkg=com.testserver id=27 notification=Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x2 color=0x00000000 actions=1 vis=PRIVATE)
I/JSONDATAPOSTMETHOd( 2347): /**/JSON POST method to be called...
I/JSONPOSTBEGIN( 2347): Beginning of JSON POST
D/NotificationService(  972): [csl] buzzBeepBlinkLocked() zenMode = 3, zenConfig = ZenModeConfig[allowCalls=true,allowMessages=false,allowFrom=contacts,allowEvents=false,allowMusic=false,allowAlarm=true,allowVibrate=true,allowLight=true,sleepMode=null,sleepStart=22.0,sleepEnd=7.0,conditionComponents=null,conditionIds=null,exitCondition=null,exitConditionComponent=null]
V/NotificationService(  972): pkg=com.testserver canInterrupt=true intercept=false
D/LBSSystemMonitorService(  972): handleMessage what - 7
V/NotificationService(  972): Interrupting!
D/Wiper_jni(  972): Send Passive Location.
D/PhoneStatusBar( 1286): updateNotification pkg=com.testserver;id=27
D/FastDormancyService( 4139): detect mobile data activity! isAlarmExpired: false  mFDset: 3
D/FastDormancyService( 4139): sent:1 received:0
D/FastDormancyService( 4139): scheduling timer:1000ms Alarm:10000ms
I/XiaomiFirewall( 1385): firewall pkgName:com.testserver, result:0x0
D/IconCustomizer( 1478): Content Ratio = 1.1294118  
V/NotificationService(  972): enqueueNotificationInternal: pkg=com.miui.securitycenter id=1000 notification=Notification(pri=2 contentView=com.miui.securitycenter/0x7f030009 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x2 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
D/NotificationService(  972): [csl] buzzBeepBlinkLocked() zenMode = 3, zenConfig = ZenModeConfig[allowCalls=true,allowMessages=false,allowFrom=contacts,allowEvents=false,allowMusic=false,allowAlarm=true,allowVibrate=true,allowLight=true,sleepMode=null,sleepStart=22.0,sleepEnd=7.0,conditionComponents=null,conditionIds=null,exitCondition=null,exitConditionComponent=null]
V/NotificationService(  972): pkg=com.miui.securitycenter canInterrupt=true intercept=false
V/NotificationService(  972): Interrupting!
I/MSM-irqbalance(  435): Decided to move IRQ65 from CPU4 to CPU7
D/PhoneStatusBar( 1286): updateNotification pkg=com.miui.securitycenter;id=1000
D/FastDormancyService( 4139): detect mobile data activity! isAlarmExpired: false  mFDset: 3
D/FastDormancyService( 4139): sent:0 received:1
D/FastDormancyService( 4139): scheduling timer:1000ms Alarm:10000ms
D/InputStream( 2347): Error org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://www.testserver.com refused
I/JSONPOSTEND( 2347): End of JSON data post methos...
V/NotificationService(  972): enqueueNotificationInternal: pkg=com.testserver id=27 notification=Notification(pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x2 color=0x00000000 actions=1 vis=PRIVATE)
/WifiService(  972): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@9a93161}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace?

Comment: @krish added stack trace

Comment: So were you able to solve this?